# Use Counter in Loop Functions Async Callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdftotext

I have a PDF and wish to extract each page of text to it's own document. So that 1.txt contains all text from the first page, 2.txt contains all the text from the second page, and so on...

However, by the time it has to write the file, the counter i is already at pages, I only end up with the last page saved to a text file.

```
  let pages = 8
  for (var i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
    var option = {from: i, to: i + 1};
    pdfUtil.pdfToText(toFolder + "document.pdf", option, function(err, data) {
      if (err) throw(err);
      fs.writeFile(toFolder + (option.to) + '.txt', data, (err) => {
        console.log("file saved", option.to)
      })
    });
  }
```

Why does option.to always equal 9 when it comes time to save?

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap you code inside of loop in IIFE like this:

```
  let pages = 8
  for (var i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
    var option = {from: i, to: i + 1};
    (function(option) {
      pdfUtil.pdfToText(toFolder + "document.pdf", option, function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw(err);
        fs.writeFile(toFolder + (option.to) + '.txt', data, (err) => {
           console.log("file saved", option.to)
        })
      });
    })(option);
  }
```

Comment: can you please explain your solution a bit? Why to we need to wrap that portion in IIFE ?

Comment: when dealing with async in js, you need to watch what you passing inside that callback function. In this case object `option` was created once and assigned new values each iteration. And `option` in callback is just a reference to an `options` inside loop. So you need to clone that `option` for each callback function. The easiest way is to use IIFE. You can learn more about it here: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/javascript/immediately-invoked-function-expression-iife

Answer (score 0):

This is because of scoping. `var option` is a single variable, and every time through the loop it's not making a new variable, it's updating the existing one.

Try `let option` first of all. If that doesn't work, please answer back. `let` has block scope, meaning every time through the loop you're making a new `option` variable.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17783384)

Comment: It literally answers every aspect of the question. It shows what to do to avoid the issue -- using `let` avoids the issue -- and it explains why it's an issue. @NigelRen

Comment: Answers should not be a series of 'try this', then that and if it doesn't work 'answer back'.  If you have some suggestions of what they need to check, they should be left as comments and not as an answer.